# Woocommerce switch tag to category and category to tag on products

Tags: phpmyadmin, woocommerce

I need help with woocommerce in wordpress. I have 2000 products in store, each of them has several tags and several categories. Unfortunately I need to switch them and doing it manually would be the hell. I have found, that there might be a solution for that via phpmyadmin.

1. Query to rename product_cat to temp
2. Query to rename product_tag to product_cat
3. Query to rename temp to product_tag
   All in the wp_term_taxonomy table.

Could you please help me with that or do you have more elegant solution? I have no knowledge of sql and queries, but if you simplify it step by step, I am able to understand what is neccessary to be done :)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the first query to type in the SQL box via phpMyAdmin: ALTER TABLE wp_term_taxonomy CHANGE product_cat temp INT(11) NOT NULL.

You should be able to figure out the other two queries.

Comment: Hello, thank you, but I have this error message: http://www.screencast.com/t/S6sHklt2
What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks for help.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the answer to ALTER TABLE wp_term_taxonomy CHANGE `product_cat` `temp` INT(11) NOT NULL;

Here I assume that the current type of product_cat is INT and the column has the NOT NULL attribute. By the way, it would be much easier to open in phpMyAdmin this table, go to Structure and for each column, click on Change and directly change its name (do it one column at the time).